# I am not able to pick up link of the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to pick up the URL the user is currently on and paste it on the Input box in html page.

This is my HTML Page

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <h1> 
                LinkLet
            </h1>
            Email the Link <input type="text" name="myinputbox" class="form1" id="myinputbox"><br>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my JS Page

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab)
{
    var newURL = "Link.html";
    chrome.tabs.create({url: newURL});
});
var url = document.URL;
var elem = document.getElementById("myinputbox");
elem.value = url;
```

Comment: So you repost another question? Dude, open Chrome developer tools and debug your JS.

Comment: Well i did that but i am not able to get it.but i am not able to capture it.I am using an extension to catch the link. hope that does not interfere with the code?